# Actualización Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Necesito actualizar una versión de Jquery, concretamente la 1.8.3 a la 3.5.
Investigando he visto que colocando el script de la versión a actualizar en el  junto con el script de migrate consigo que la consola del navegador me informe de errores para poder ir solventándolos uno a uno con las funciones que están deprecadas.
Mi consulta es:

¿debo hacer ese procedicmiento versión a versión hasta llegar a la 3.5 (1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6...etc)? ¿o hay un salto por ejemplo hacer una migración hasta la 1.12.4, luego salto a la 2.2.4 y luego ya definitivamente a la 3.5?
Es la primera vez que me pongo con Jquery y no sé por dónde van los tiros.
Muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalmente, cuando una biblioteca/herramienta cambia de versión mayor, quiere decir que hay cambios que van a romper algo con respecto a versiones anteriores.

Si saltas de jQuery 1.x a 2.x y luego de 2.x a 3.x puede que te encuentres haciendo cambios en los mismos sitios dos veces (aunque improbable). Si sabes que vas a estar usando la versión 3.x, te diría que saltes directamente de la que estés usando a la que quieras. De ese modo te ahorrarás un paso *innecesario* que puede introducir otros problemas.

Otra cosa a tener en cuenta sería, ¿seguro que quieres saltar de 1.x a 3.x? Normalmente las versiones más modernas son más seguras y más eficientes, pero también se puede perder soporte para sistemas que no están tan actualizados.

Por ejemplo, jQuery 1.x funciona en Internet Explorer, pero 2.x y 3.x contienen cambios que no funcionarán en IE. Dependiendo de los navegadores que quieras soportar, puede que el cambio no sea conveniente.

Comment: Gracias, efectivamente tengo que cambiar a 3.x por temas de seguridad. Está contemplado la falta de soporte a IE así que no hay ningún problema. ¿Recomiendas que use la herramienta migrate o que directamente vaya por la consola solucionando los fallos? Gracias :)